# My ssl certificate generates with lets encrypt but does not install

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt, acme

I'm using [this][1] library to generate SSL certificates. My storage generates 4 files: certificate.pem, private_key.pem, chain.pem, and fullchain.pem.

I want to install this certificate in acquia cloud using their Rest API post endpoint to install ssl certificate. The payload looks like the following:

```
{
  "legacy": 0,
  "certificate": "pasted the content inside our certificate.pem",
  "private_key": "pasted the content inside private_key.pem",
  "ca_certificates": "pasted the content inside the fullchain.pem",
  "label": "My New Cert"
}
```

When I send a request, I received an error to contact they api owner support, and searching around through the server log I came across this:

```
 Error response: 500 (Internal Server Error). Error message: Site certificate CA chain certificates are out of order..
```

What exactly does this error mean by saying out of order?

Comment: You forgot the link.

Comment: Try to use `chain.pem` instead of `fullchain.pem` in the `ca_certificates` option.